# Timer does its work just once

Tags: java, android, timer

I need a regular method in my app. The problem is: the following timer in the code does its action just once. And the timer does it only(the one time) if I do an action(touch the display) after the time(2000) is over. Do you know what I mean? Maybe it has sth. to do with the "OnTouchListener"?

```
public class DrawView extends View implements OnTouchListener {

    Timer mTimer = new Timer();

    public DrawView(Context context) {
       mTimer.schedule(new Task(this), 2000);
    }

    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    }
}

class Task extends TimerTask {

  private DrawView mDw;

  public Task(DrawView dw){
      mDw = dw;
  }

  public void run() {
        mDw.newgame();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you both. But i have still the problem that "the task" do its work only if i touch the display.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`shcedule(task, 0, 2000)` - use the 3-argument method. The second argument is the delay, and the third is the period. See [`Timer#schedule(..)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long%29)

Answer (score 0):

The timer is doing what he should do. You should use the schedule Method of the Timer but instead [scheduleAtFixedRate](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.util.TimerTask,%20java.util.Date,%20long%29)().

Comment: Thank you but i used the 3-arguments method